My wallet is compromised and it rejects my signature
My wallet is compromised although I still have full access on it. I have my seed phrase and private key also but the hacker seemed to have done something to my wallet address for it seems to reject my signature every time a do a transaction. I tried to send balance to my compromised account and it goes through but when I tried to send back the balance to my other account it keeps rejecting. Is it possible to at least get my wallet to accept my signature back?
